# Install keras in Anaconda3 Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, deep-learning, keras

I was trying to install keras in in anaconda in Ubuntu. I followed instuction from this [site](http://www.codesofinterest.com/2016/11/setting-up-keras-anaconda-ubuntu.html). All my packages are installed properly. Also in `pip list` I can see keras. But when I'm trying to import keras it's saying `"no module called keras"`.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Where are you importing `keras`? In a script, console or `jupyter notebook`?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko: Thanks for your comment. I tried to install in both console as well as jupyter notebok. Got the same error.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko: Somehow this time I could install Keras. Thanks for taking your time to help me with the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, you need switch `conda env` to your target_env

```
source activate target_env
```

second, use `pip` install keras

```
pip install keras
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply use `conda install keras` and it works for me.